# How to customize each column in Highcharts stacked column

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, stacked-chart

Hi I need to customize each column in highcharts stacked column

[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8tdH.png)

I this implementation i have given like this

```
{
categories:["6-7","7-8"]
series: [{
        name: 'pass',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Fail',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }]
}
```

But now I need to change this implementation and i have to customize each column and add categories
how do i achieve this i'm having a array like this

```
[{"pass":2,"fail":3,"category":"6-7","percentage":"20%"}
{"pass":5,"fail":0,"category":"7-8","percentage":"10%"}]
```

i wanted like this

```
|percentage|
------------
|  pass    |
|  fail    |
-----------------
  category
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to preprocess your data to create series structure required by Highcharts. The 'category' label is achievable by using `name` property and 'percentage' by stack-labels formatter:

```
var data = [{
    "pass": 2,
    "fail": 3,
    "category": "6-7",
    "percentage": "20%"
}, {
    "pass": 5,
    "fail": 0,
    "category": "7-8",
    "percentage": "10%"
}];

var series = [{
    name: 'Pass',
    data: []
}, {
    name: 'Fail',
    data: []
}];

data.forEach(function(dataObj) {
    series[0].data.push({
        y: dataObj.pass,
        name: dataObj.category,
        percentage: dataObj.percentage
    });
    series[1].data.push({
        y: dataObj.fail,
        name: dataObj.category
    });
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.axis.series[0].options.data[this.x].percentage;
            }
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: series
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nfbq2soe/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.formatter